# adding textview values in asynchtask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Now i am doing an android application.In that application I am using asynchtask class to parse json data and i have to set that values in to ui.My program is like this.

```
class Activity
{
textview tv;
oncreate()
{
    setcontentview(layout);
    tv=(textview)findviewbyid(id);
    call to pageload()
}
class PageLoad extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean>
{
    doInBackground()
    {
        json parsing
        tv.setText(data);
    }
}
}
```

But I couldn't set the value from pageload class.Please help me friends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to understand that doInBackground() runs on a different thread to the UI, therefore you cannot access the UI here. AsyncTask has two other methods:

- `onPreExecute()` - before `doInBackground()` is run
- `onPostExecute()` - after `doInBackground()` is run, can receive the result of the work done by doInBackground()

You need to pass the result of `doInBackground()` to `onPostExecute()` where you can then set the TextView's text.

I would suggest you read Google's article on how to use the Asynctask which can be found at http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html and look at the class [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Example Code

```
private class MyAsynctask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

     protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
         //do something heavy or resource intensive
         String data = resultOfSomeWork();
         return data;
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
         myTextView.setText(result);
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

you can also use `onProgressUpdate()` of `AsyncTask`

You can call it using `publishProgress(values)` from your doInBackGround().

And set Text in your textbox in the onProgressUpdate().

Answer (score 1):

**You can't use UI thread** in `doInBack..()` of AsyncTask (As its only worker thread). Use `onPostExecute()` for it (If you want to make any ui related changes do in `onPreExecute()` or `onPostExecuted()`).

Just go through [Android-AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) and look at how it works.

Answer (score -2):

You can't update UI from AsyncTask thread, it most be done on the main thread. You can use [handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) for this.